# PayPal REST API - billing plans & agreements & VAT tax

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am reading through **PayPal SDK docs** and answers here on stackoverflow. I understand that if product/price changes, then each customer needs to have his own plan and agreement. Now, my question is **how to deal with VAT taxes**? The product price is the same, only the tax % differs. Do I still need to create a new plan for each customer?

Alternatively, would it make sense to make different plans for different VAT rates? E.g. Monthly-19, Monthly-21, etc. Then I would subscribe to the specific tax Plan. Another option would be to have a plan for each EU country and one plan for the rest of the world.

What is the preferred option for this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plans are static. All of their pricing information, including tax, is specified when creating a plan.

If pricing varies for a new situation, then you need to create a new plan.

Comment: I understand that plans are static. What do you think of different plans for different vat rates? Or just create a new plan for each client and don't bother with reused plans?